# Talend user component not updated in Admin Console

Tags: talend

Facing some issue in Talend Admin Console, the jobs that are running from IDE is not running in Admin Console. The resources are not getting updated in Admin Console.

Following are the issue that I am facing now.

1) I have edited a Talend user component and able see its change when I run from Talend IDE. But this change is not reflected when I run through Admin Console.

2) I have created a new routine for the job and when I run the job from talend IDE its working. But I am getting a ClassNotFound error in Admin Console.

Link which discuss the same : http://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=10103

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Talend admin console will use something called the "commandline" to compile and execute your jobs. The commandline is a Talend client that is running without the GUI. Any changes to components you make in your Client will need to be made in the commandline also. Usually you would just copy the component folder to the correct (same place as your client) in the commandline.

Comment: And I was able to solve the routine issue by adding the routine to routine dependency list by right clicking on the Job from Talend IDE.